# Creating OpenCL memory object from OpenGL ES mipmaps

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opencl, mipmaps

My android app passes in an OpenGL texture2D to my OpenCL kernel, however when I use clCreateFromGLTexture2D() with mipmap level 1, I get CL_INVALID_MIPLEVEL.

I am creating my OpenGL texture and generating mipmaps like this:

```
    GLES20.glGenTextures ( 2, targetTex, 0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTex[0]);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The texture is then rendered to by binding it with a FBO:

```
    targetFramebuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, targetFramebuffer);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, targetFramebuffer.get(0));
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTex[0], 0);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I then create a cl memory object like so:

```
    mem_images[0] = clCreateFromGLTexture2D(m_clContext, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, in_tex, &err);
```

The memory object is created successfully when the miplevel is set to 0 and all the kernels work fine. It's only when the miplevel is set to that the above function call gives me CL_INVALID_MIPLEVEL error.

OpenCL specification docs (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture2D.html) say that a possible reason could be that the OpenGL implementation does not support creating from non-zero mipmap levels. However I don't know if this is definitely the case and am not sure how to find out.

**EDIT:**
After Andon's reply I changed my OpenGL texture generation to following:

```
    GLES20.glGenTextures ( 2, targetTex, 0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTex[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

and after drawing into the FBO which is bound with the texture, this is how I generate mipmaps:

```
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTex[0]);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GLES20.glFinish();
```

I still get the same error when trying to create a CL memory object from GL texture with mipmap level not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is something very unusual about the dimensions of your second-level mipmap in this code. The dimensions of ***mipmap*** LOD N+1 should be LOD N{w,h}/2. You *can* have LODs with the same resolution in GL, but those LODs will not be mipmaps. To make your 2D texture mipmap complete, you need log2 (max (width,height))-1 LODs in addition to the base image **0**, and each should be 1/4 the resolution (1/2 each dimension) of the last. I have to agree with CL on this one, LOD 1 is not really a mipmap.

Moreover, you are calling `glGenerateMipmap (...)` on a newly created texture that has no data store. That is a meaningless thing to do, `glGenerateMipmap (...)` will build your mip-chain for you starting with the base LOD image; at the time you called this, there was no base LOD.

Your call to `GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` really ought to be moved to a point ***after*** you draw into your FBO. Done properly, you do not have to manually allocate storage for lower detail mipmap LODs. This function will take care of that for you. Thus, you should actually remove the code that allocates LOD 1 in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the changes but I still get the same error.
However, +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @amirhbp: In this case, you must have "an OpenGL implementation that does not support creating from non-zero mipmap levels." Because assuming `image_width` and `image_height` are non-zero, you should have a mipmap complete texture now.

Comment: is there anyway to check this?
Also, shouldn't OpenGL ES generate an error upon calling GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D) if the OpenGL implementation didn't support this.
and does that mean Android doesn't support mipmaps? Because I am using Android's OpenGL ES :/

Comment: No, `GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D)` generates a set of mipmaps from the base image level, which is **0** by default. That is different from what you are trying to do in your CL code.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that Android's OpenGL ES doesn't support creation of cl memory objects from non-zero mipmap levels.
and there is no way to check this? like an extension or something?

Comment: @amirhbp: I would not know, I have never tried to use OpenCL on an embedded platform. However, I can tell you for certain that Android does not have a ***single*** OpenGL ES implementation. There are at least 4 major hardware vendors that have their own implementations, and I am sure there are dozens of tiny vendors I have never heard of that do as well.